# Getting data in the random order

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an sql query and wanted to show data in randomized order like on every refresh it should bring up with random data

Here is my code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['new_list'])) {
    $class_id = $_POST['get_class_id'];
    $user_id  = $_POST['user_id'];

    $sql2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM get_help WHERE class = '$class_id' AND status = 'Pending' AND user_id != '$user_id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        $sql3  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '".$record['user_id']."' AND btc_email != ''");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql3)) {
        $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3); 
?>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><?php echo $data2["first_name"] . " " . $data2["last_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data2["email"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data2["phone"]; ?></td>
            <td>
            <p>
            Click donate to see receipient bitcoin address. Input Hash ID after transfer    
            </p>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $record['id']; ?>);" name="donate" class="btn btn-red">Donate</button>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>  
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using ORDER BY id in your first query, you can use ORDER BY RAND() instead. This will produce a randomised result for your display:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM get_help WHERE class = '$class_id' AND status = 'Pending' AND user_id != '$user_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Remember to use htmlentities() around your $_POST data to make sure that it's safe for the database query, eg:

```
$class_id = htmlentities($_POST['get_class_id']);
$user_id  = htmlentities($_POST['user_id']);
```